# Errors on install WP 5.02 (fresh install) , Civicrm 5.82, PHP 7.2.13 (xampp)

Tags: wordpress, error, installation

I installed civicrm 5.82 on a fresh install of Wordpress 5.02 with PHP 7.2.13 (xampp). Went through civicrm setup, then saw a few PHP warnings on the CiviCRM Home page. This is running on my local dev computer (Win 10) and I have HTTPS enabled.

The errors are:

- Warning: get_headers(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in F:....\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Utils\Check\Component\Env.php on line 917
- Warning: get_headers(): Failed to enable crypto in F:....\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Utils\Check\Component\Env.php on line 917
- Warning: get_headers(https://civicrm.test/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/jquery/css/images/arrow.png): failed to open stream: operation failed in F:....\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Utils\Check\Component\Env.php on line 917

It seemed to install fine. I'm going through the settings and entering values with no problem so far.

Is there anything I should check or watch out for due to these errors?

Thanks.

Comment: Check if you are able to load the system status page correctly - `Administer -> Administer Console -> System Status`. The error relates to the SSL certificate configured on your server. Double check if it is configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Status page appears to load correctly. There is a "Timestamp Mismatch" error and a " PHP Missing Extension mcrypt" error. I think PHP 7.2 doesn't even have mcrypt anymore (http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php)

Comment: OK I'm not sure how to check if ssl is configured correctly. The only thing my error logs say about it is, "OpenSSL/1.1.1a PHP/7.2.13 configured -- resuming normal operations". Apache access log shows a bunch of successful calls to various images.

Comment: Running on Windows should work, but if you're new to Civi you'll find more documentation and people around to help you on a Linux platform.  One option is: install VirtualBox, create a VM, install Ubuntu, install buildkit, create dev sites with civibuild